# Hide Null values from Report

Tags: sql

Build a report using this SP.  If the Report has no data to display we should only show the  tbl_CompanyProfile, but the report is showing all null fields from the second select.  My concern is: How to hide the null values from the second select and show only the tbl_CompanyProfile fields?

```
SELECT Company_Name, Company_Address, Company_ContactNo, Company_Email, 
Company_Website, 'NULL' AS NAME, 'NULL' AS DATE, 0 AS AMOUNT, 
'NULL' AS DEPARTMENT, 0 AS Age, @from AS StartDate, @to AS EndDate
FROM     tbl_CompanyProfile

UNION ALL

SELECT '--' , '--' , '--' , '--' , '--' , tbl_IPD.ipd_pfname + ' ' + tbl_IPD.ipd_plname AS NAME,
CONVERT(VARCHAR, tbl_IPD.ipd_doa, 103) AS DATE, 
ISNULL(SUM(tbl_fee.fee_amount), 0) AS AMOUNT, tblDepartment.DeptName AS DEPARTMENT,
tbl_IPD.ipd_age AS Age, @from AS StartDate, @to AS EndDate
FROM     tbl_fee LEFT OUTER JOIN
tbl_IPD ON tbl_fee.ipd_id = tbl_IPD.ipd_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
tblDepartment ON tbl_IPD.ipd_dpt = tblDepartment.DeptId
WHERE  (tbl_IPD.ipd_doa BETWEEN @from AND @to)
GROUP BY tbl_IPD.ipd_pfname, tbl_IPD.ipd_plname, tbl_IPD.ipd_doa, 
tblDepartment.DeptName, tbl_IPD.ipd_age
```

Comment: Do you have to have `UNION ALL` or can your SP have multiple individual queries?

Comment: I edited the question.  Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting 'NULL' as a string value.  This is not the value NULL.  If you change 'NULL' to NULL by removing the single quotes, the report should display the values as blank.

Comment: No way.  I must have been over-thinking it.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
having SUM(tbl_fee.fee_amount) > 0
```

To the second select in your union.

This will keep the second select from returning rows.